# Unable to access angular scope from dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am trying to access a scope using the following statement:

```
$("#myCarousel").scope()
```

I have also tried

```
angular.element("#myCarousel").scope()
```

this statement works fine in IE10 chrome, firefox etc.  I have tried an older version of angular 1.1 and it still does not work, I am allowing the controller to load before running the above statement, the only response i get is undefined.  I have searched for a solution to this problem but cant see anything.  I am using the IE emulator in IE10 when getting this result.

The page is binding the available data from the scope as well.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Are you sure you are waiting for both angular *and* the DOM to load? Can you provide any code?

Comment: Probably a timing issue. Are you sure you are trying to access it after DOM is loaded. Also did you try `angular.element(document.getElementById("myCarousel")).scope()`

Answer (score 0):

To get the raw element from jQuery:

```
var el = $("#myCarousel")[0];
```

Then to get the angular scope from that,

```
var scope = angular.element(el).scope();
```

Or in a single line:

```
angular.element($("#myCarousel")[0]).scope();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How did you know OP is using jquery?

Comment: ahh i missed that.. LOL!! But OP says it works while running from the console of the browser. It must just be a timing issue i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above and still got just undefined response.

I've managed to get the scope to return now i changed the #mycarousel element to be the one directly below the declaration in the mark up for the controller and it started to work, strange was working in all other browsers, thanks for your feedback anyway.